# What is this mountainous relief feature?

Tags: mountains, topography

[image]

I was going through an old Indian survey map, when I saw this unfamiliar relief feature. It looked like a cross between a hachure and saddle. Could someone help identify it?

Comment: the location and scale of the map might be helpful when identifying this.can this be farming related?

Comment: It is likely a surface mine.

Comment: Are you asking about the relief itself or about the symbol? Is the symbol absent from the map legend?

Comment: The map appears to be a Survey of India map, sheet G43S10. This appears to be near Abu, Rajasthan, India at about 24.56°N, 72.72°E. For orientation, I found it useful to locate St. Mary's High School at the top edge of the image from the question. Using Google Maps, I cannot discern anything interesting in the area circled green: it appears to be just a rock outcropping. According to the Survey of India map legend this seems to be the signature for "rocky slope", but I could be wrong (I am not at all familiar with these maps).